# EF4 - custom ObjectContext and inheritance question

Tags: entity-framework

Spinning further on the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917718) I had. Let's say I inherit BlogEntry and Comment from Post. I now want to customize them a bit. A comment to a blog post does not need a title but a comment needs a user reference so I move these two fields out from Post and into Comment and Blog entry like this:

```
public abstract class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class BlogEntry : Post
{
    public virtual string Header { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment : Post
{
    public virtual string Header { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogEntry BlogEntry { get; set; }
}
```

Now I create my custom object context:

```
public class EntityContext : System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
{
    public EntityContext() : base("name=Entities", "Entities")
    {
        this.Blogs = CreateObjectSet<Blog>();
        this.Posts = CreateObjectSet<Post>();
        this.Entries = CreateObjectSet<BlogEntry>();
        this.Comments = CreateObjectSet<Comment>(); 
    }
    public ObjectSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public ObjectSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public ObjectSet<BlogEntry> Entries { get; set; }
    public ObjectSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

This gives me the following actually quite descriptive error message:

> Test method threw exception:
>   System.ArgumentException:  There are
>   no EntitySets defined for the
>   specified entity type 'BlogEntry'.  If
>   'BlogEntry' is a derived type, use the
>   base type instead.  For example, you
>   would see this error if you called
>   CreateObjectSet()
>   and DiscontinuedProduct is a known
>   entity type but is not directly mapped
>   to an EntitySet.  The
>   DiscontinuedProduct type may be a
>   derived type where the parent type is
>   mapped to the  EntitySet or the
>   DiscontinuedProduct type might not be
>   mapped to an EntitySet at all.
>   Parameter name: TEntity

Now I am not a master of inheritance and stuff but the way I see this would be to add a set of Entries and Comments as ObjectSet< Post> that would solve my problems?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you create an `ObjectSet` for a base type (i.e. `Post`) you can't create one for derived types too, because you can retrieve instances of all types in the inheritance hierarchy from that one `ObjectSet`.

i.e. `ctx.Posts.OfType<BlogEntry>()` would return BlogEntry(s).

So the answer is to simply remove the other two sets.

If yo need to do an add for example you can do this:

```
ctx.Posts.AddObject(new BlogEntry {....});
```

no problem at all.

To help you write queries more easily you could probably add a couple of properties to your ObjectContext that look like this:

```
public ObjectQuery<BlogEntity> Blogs{
   get{
       return ctx.Posts.OfType<BlogEntry>() as ObjectQuery<BlogEntry>;
   }
}
```

and the same for comments.

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Yeah I haven't had time to look at it further. What you say sounds true. I just finished writing a huge blog post about my findings today. Looks like I have to write another one tomorrow about POCO inheritance :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip with just removing the bagage! :)