# How to properly display or save inheriting classes into database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have two classes, named `Text` and `Image`, which both inherit from the abstract class `Item`. We've mapped this in a `.edmx` file and have generated a database from there.

Now, whenever attempting to get a `Text` or `Image` from the database, I'm facing the following exception:

```
There are no EntitySets defined for the specified entity type 'ModelLibrary.Text'.
If 'ModelLibrary.Text' is a derived type, use the base type instead.
Parameter name: TEntity
```

I can't access or save `Item` classes, since they are abstract classes and since they never contain the information associated with `Text` or `Image` classes.

The piece of code I'm using to try and access the data:

```
ProjectEntities context = new ProjectEntities(); //this inherits from ObjectContext and was generated by EF

var textRepo = new TextRepository(context);
var lstTexts = textRepo.GetAll();
foreach (var i in lstTexts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.textTitle);
}
```

The `textRepo` class is used for accessing and saving to the database. I get the exception on the constructor of the class the `textRepo` inherits from `(DataRepository)`:

```
protected DataRepository(ObjectContext context)
{
    Context = context;
    ObjectSet = Context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
}
```

I've already done some research on the exception, and have found this question: [EF4 - custom ObjectContext and inheritance question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/923315)

The answer to the question is actually something that is already supposed to happen (the making of an ObjectSet for the specific type). I just seem to get the exception at the line that is supposed to prevent the exception.

Now, I would like to know what could possibly be going wrong or what I am missing. Do I need to do something extra because of the inheritance? Mind you, I'm a little new with Entity Framework, so my apologies if I'm making a very obvious mistake here. If you need more information or code, feel free to ask.

EDIT: To be more specific on the exception, I get it on the `ObjectSet = Context.CreateObjectSet<T>();` line. I can't add much to the piece of testing code, since I already get the exception at the constructor of the baseclass of the `textRepo` class, namely the `DataRepository` class.

Comment: With regard to the answer you have linked: Did you try the solution proposed there to use `OfType`, i.e. `Context.Items.OfType<Text>() as ObjectQuery<Text>`?

Comment: I haven't, since I didn't really know where that line should be placed. I'll take another look, and maybe risk putting the line all over the place and see where it might work.

Comment: I have circumvented the entire problem by just ditching the `.edmx` inheritance completely, and replacing it with 0..1 to 1 relations. It's a tad inconvenient, but I've found things elsewhere in my project where dropping the inheritance is somewhat preferable.